# how to package resources in a leiningen project

Tags: clojure, leiningen

in the sample project,

https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

on `line 217`, there is a directive for including non-code files :

```
:resource-paths ["src/main/resource"] ; non-code files included in classpath/jar
```

I have a `resources` folder in my project and this line in my project.clj

```
:resource-paths ["resources"] ; non-code files included in classpath/jar
```

however, when I run `lein jar` to generate the `.jar` file, it does not package up the `resources` folder.

Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it did get packaged. I just was not looking in the right spot:

from:
    [Resources in Clojure applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009829/resources-in-clojure-applications?rq=1)

> 'Leiningen borrows the convention for resources from maven, with slightly different folder layouts. The rule states that the resources folder must be used as a compile time classpath root, meaning that leiningen is right in putting all the files inside resources folder in the root location inside the jar.'

I thought that a resources directory would get created with the jar itself but `lein jar` copied all the files in the resources directory to the root of the jar.

Comment: Hi @zcaudate I'm trying to solve this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020288/howto-package-my-project-resource-paths-to-use-as-project-dependency but I think it's different from this solution, isn't it?