# Clojure resources path and others

Tags: clojure

How do we get the path to the resources directory in a lein app project?

I have one way that I've seen, this

```
(clojure.java.io/resource "file.txt")
```

The doc says "Returns the URL for a named resource" but I'm confused by this...not sure it is something I'd want to use. Suppose this case:

```
/project.clj
/src
/src/core.clj
/resources/A.txt
/resources/B.txt
```

Say file A.txt contains a sentence in lower case letters. And say that I want to read it and then write the same sentence to B.txt in upper case. How do I even tell the project to write to `/resources/whatever.txt`?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this, resources are often stored within the JAR and are read-only. I don't think they are the right tool for doing this.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I guess I would just need a reliable way to read from resources. Just wanted to make sure I'm doing it right.

Comment: Here are the best answers I've seen to that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009829/resources-in-clojure-applications