# Clojure Uberjar not loading resource file

Tags: jar, clojure, resources, leiningen, uberjar

I use lein uberjar to create a standalone jar of an application.

When executing

```
java -jar dataloader-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar,
```

it crashes with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a file:
jar:file:dataloader-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar!/configuration.json
```

I load the file via:

```
(ns dataloader.configuration
  (:gen-class)
  (:require [cheshire.core :refer :all]
            [clojure.java.io :as io]))

(def data-file
  (io/file
    (io/resource "configuration.json")))
```

project.clj

```
(defproject dataloader "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Used for loading stage data into local vagrantbox"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :resource-paths ["resources"]
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [clojurewerkz/elastisch "2.1.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.3.7"]
                 [mysql/mysql-connector-java "5.1.32"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "0.2.6"]
                 [org.clojure/data.codec "0.1.0"]
                 [cheshire "5.5.0"]]

  :main ^:skip-aot dataloader.core
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}})
```

resources/configuration.json is put into the root folder of the jar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`clojure.java.io/resource` returns a URL, not a file. That's why you can call `slurp` on it. The error message is telling you that it's not a file, unfortunately it's not telling you that it's a URL.

Of course you could open the url with the java.net.URL api although that would be overkill in this case.

Comment: I call slurp on the file afterwards. The problem is, that the file is not found. When developing, it works.

Comment: No, the error says "Not a file." It doesn't say "File not found." See this: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/resource

Comment: You were right. I had to slurp directly on the resource.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to read the content of the `configuration.json` file, do not call `io/file`. Instead, use `slurp` function, like that:

```
(def config (slurp (io/resource "configuration.json")))
```

Comment: I call slurp on the file afterwards. The problem is, that the file is not found. When developing, it works.

Comment: Is it possible for me to write to this configuration file after?