# How to include non-Clojure source files in Leiningen deploy to Clojars?

Tags: deployment, clojure, leiningen, clojars

I deployed a project to Clojars the other day in order to be able to effortlessly use it as a dependency in other projects. Today I tried to use it and it broke saying it wasn't able to find a file (let's call it `grammar.ebnf`). This is a file describing a grammar that is then `slurp`ed up in one of my Clojure modules. I made it as a separate file just to separate the grammar from the logic using the grammar. I located it in the same directory as the other source files

Clearly it's not being included in the deployment to Clojars. How do I make sure that this file gets included alongside the .clj files when I deploy using `lein deploy clojars`?

**EDIT:** See comments below

Comment: @AlanThompson Yeah what ended up helping was a resources directory as you suggested, pointing to it with `resource-paths` in project.clj, and then accessing the resources like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32237723/353715

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  What you need is to make a `./resources` directory, and place files inside of it.  These files will be included on the classpath of your project, running either locally or after creating a JAR file.

For example, we can make a file `resources/stuff.txt`

```
> echo "happens" > resources/stuff.txt
```

and access it like:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [clojure.java.io :as io]
    [clojure.string :as str]))

(dotest
  (is= (str/trim (slurp (io/resource "stuff.txt")))
    "happens"))
```

with result

```sh
    > lein clean; lein test
    
    ------------------------------------------
       Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 14.0.1
    ------------------------------------------
    
    Testing tst.demo.core
    
    Ran 2 tests containing 1 assertions.
    0 failures, 0 errors.
```